# Convert JSON to CSV using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, xml, azure-logic-apps

I need to convert every JSON message from Azure Data Lake Store into CSV record and store again in Azure Data Lake Store. Then i plan to use Azure Data Factory to load every CSV record into Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

So, as first step i am using Logic Apps to read JSON message from Azure Data Lake Store and using Parse JSON and then Create CSV table.

But getting error message in Parse JSON step:
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '1' and column '2732': 'Required property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'.

Could you please help how to fix this error?. Or you even propose different ways as i even tried with Liquid Templates, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you tried to add some of your code behind, so people can have a grasp what you're trying to do? Especially the part that throws the error.

Comment: Logic app support null-conditional operator so you can do something like that `my_json?.myproperty1?.myproperty2`. also depends how big is your json but you may want to use azure functions as you will be billed for each action in the logic app

Answer (score 0):

For a process whose primary task is format conversion, **Azure Data Factory** is most probably the path you should try first.

ADF has native support for JSON and CSV (Text).  ADF's JSON support is really good, but there might be instances where using a **Logic App and Liquid transform** might be useful as a pre-processor as well.